# A more compact way to do a singleton with a parameter

Tags: c#, singleton

I am not really that good at patterns.  (But I do realize that they are very important.)  I have a scenario that needs a singleton but also needs to take a parameter.  Normally for a singleton I just make a static method that does a:

```
return _instance ?? (_instance = new SingletonClass());
```

But when a parameter is involved you either have to pass the parameter every time to access things (just in case that is the time you are going to be doing the constructing) or do something like I did here:

```
public class PublicFacingSingleton
{
    private readonly string _paramForSingleton;
    public PublicFacingSingleton(string paramForSingleton)
    {
        _paramForSingleton = paramForSingleton;
    }

    private PrivateFacingSingleton _access;
    public PrivateFacingSingleton Access
    {
        get 
        { 
            // If null then make one, else return the one we have.
            return _access ?? 
                   (_access = new PrivateFacingSingleton(_paramForSingleton)); 
        }
    }
}

public class PrivateFacingSingleton
{
    private readonly ClassWithOnlyOneInstance _singleInstance;
    public PrivateFacingSingleton(string paramForSingleton)
    {
        _singleInstance = new ClassWithOnlyOneInstance(paramForSingleton);
    }

    public WorkItem ActualMethodToDoWork()
    {
        return _singleInstance.UseTheClass();
    }
}
```

and then create the `PublicFacingSigleton` and use that.  For example:

```
var publicFacingSingleton = new PublicFacingSingleton("MyParameter")
publicFacingSingleton.Access.ActualMethodToDoWork();
```

There are several problems with this.  A few of them are:

1. I have two classes now instead of one
2. An unknowing developer could still easily create a `PrivateFacingSingleton` instance.

Is there a better way that addresses my concerns but does not have me passing in a param every time I want to call `ActualMethodToDoWork()`  (ie `publicFacingSingleton.Access("MyParameter").ActualMethodToDoWork()`)

NOTE: The above code is an example taken from my actual code.  If you want to see my actual code it is [here](https://gist.github.com/793623).

Comment: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: Can you explain why you need a singleton in the first place?  I find that most people that "need" singletons really need a service locator, and singletons are just a lazy shortcut.

Comment: @Mystere Man -  I am creating a server side TFS Plugin.  But the Server Side TFS API does not really have any Work Item classes.  So I am having to use the client side API on the server.  (It is still faster than going just client side).  Anyway, the WorkItemStore takes a long time to load.  So I only want to load it once.  Hence the singleton.  (Meaning if it is has been loaded use it instead of making a new one.)

Comment: You don't want a singleton.  Singletons exist for the lifetime of the application, and don't take into account connection/disconnection semantics.  What you really need is somehting more akin to a caching pattern, such as those used with sql server connection pooling.

Answer (score 2):

This might be considered as not a solution but I do think it should be mentioned here:

When a singleton needs a parameter it probably is not a singleton.

Chances are that you will need an instance that was created with an other value for the parameter (now or in the long run)

Comment: Good point, but in this case I will only ever need one instance with one parameter.  (I am running on a TFS Server and will only ever connect to the server I am running on.  The parameter indicates what the name of the server is.)  I suppose I could try and backdoor the parameter (read it directly from the config file), but it is a bit of a hack to do that.  I would rather not.

Comment: I don't mean to sound cynical but if I got a dollar for every time a developer said " I will only ever need ..." and regretted it later I wouldn't be answering questions on the stacks ;-)

Comment: I can see what you mean.  But since I am actually running on the TFS Server that is the param, to go and connect to a different server (ie needing a different param) would require more than just a rewriting of this class.

Comment: If it is that complicated to change it and run it on an other server why is it a parameter?

Comment: Because it is different to every server that this dll will be deployed on.  I still need to know it so I can get the data that the server holds.  I just will only ever connect to one server (per instance of the application).

Comment: So how bad would it be to have two instances? Isn't the singleton overkill in this case?

Comment: Not so bad to have two or three or 10, but I don't want one created every time I update a Work Item in TFS (which is when my code is called).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a combination of singleton and factory pattern would suit your needs?

Multiple functions can be placed within your singleton class, which are instantiated only once. Meanwhile, the singleton class acts as a factory giving out the required output and also acting as an abstraction to the creation logic.

```
public class Singleton {

    private static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
    private Object FactoryOutput;

    // Private constructor prevents instantiation from other classes
    private Singleton() { }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public Object SomeClassWhichNeedsSingleInstantiation(Object Parameter)
    {
        If(FactoryOutput == null)
        {
            FactoryOutput = new FactoryOutput(Parameter);
        }
        return FactoryOutput;
    }
}
```